# Magento2 grunt error

Tags: magento2, grunt

```
> npm install -D load-grunt-config
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-52-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-D" "load-grunt-config"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/hosemart-web/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your actual context, I think it's not finding the `package.json` file. Make sure you have the following files in your Magento root:

1. package.json
2. Gruntfile.js
3. grunt-config.json

There are "sample" files usually included in the Magento root by default that can be copied/renamed in most cases.

If this doesn't help you may have grunt mis-installed or mid-configured.

- Magento Dev Docs: [Compile LESS using Grunt](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)
- Gruntjs.com: [Getting Started](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

Comment: I have all the 3 files in root & I also removed sample. I had same error for time-grunt, but it got resolved by sudo npm install --save-dev time-grunt but when I try same for load-grunt-config it doesn't work

Comment: How do you mean, `npm install --save-dev load-grunt-config` does not work? What do you see in terms of error messages, etc? Did you run `npm install` or `npm install load-grunt-config`?

Comment: when I run npm install load-grunt-confi I get the error in my question